# div width auto according to parent total width leftover

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a simple container with 2 widths.

```
<div class="holder">

    <div class="info-recieve"></div>

    <textarea class="info-send></textarea>

</div>

.holder{
 width: 335px;
 height: auto;
}
.info-recieve, .info-send{
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}
```

The .first width would be empty at start, but then it would recieve dynamic html from the textarea (like the tagging system from stack overflow).

The textarea would start with 100%, and then would adapt to the .info-recieve width, respecting the .parent width max.

Here it is the live code:

http://www2.madeinweb.com.br/jobs/sgiurd/edit-profile.html

If you guys go to the "Formação" fieldset, just type on the textarea and press enter.

Comment: In your CSS, do you have semi-colons?

Comment: Im using sass, this simple piece of code is just to show the idea.

Comment: how much text can the first one fit? what's the biggest size of the .first you want?

Comment: The max-width for both should be 100%, just like the gmail mail input for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just take `.second` of the rule you have now.

```
.first {
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QaWcd/)** (colors added for easy visibility)

Comment: @Huangism - what else would you expect to happen within a fixed width container?

Comment: It its going to be just like the taggin system of stackoverflow, i will update the question